# Positioning full-height absolute element inside relative one

Tags: html, css, css-position

Please help me to solve the quest. We have 3 div blocks. Height of the first div set to 100px (but in real world it's dynamic value). Second block has fixed height, and has another block as a child. The child block should have height stretched down to the bottom of the screen. But since our second block is relative, bottom:0 will mean bottom of the second block. What is the best practice for such cases, pure CSS please?

```css
body > div { height: 100px; }

.first { background: lightblue; }

.second {
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
}

.second div {
  position: absolute;
  background: pink;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">The height of the block may vary greately.</div>
<div class="second">
  <div>This DIV should take whole free space to the bottom of the screen.</div>
</div>
```

UPD:

I can achieve the effect by wrapping second div into additional div (width position absolute and bottom: 0) and leave it with transparent background, but then static content "behind it" become unusable. Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/n725s1nq/).

Comment: which div should take the remaining space? the second div or the child of second div? the child has height: 200px. I assume second will take it?

Comment: @jmag child should have remaining space. 200px is a random number.

Comment: Why can't you have 3 divs at the same level, not nested?

Comment: @Panglosee because nested div is a part of menu.

Comment: The only way with pure css is making the nested div to position fixed - https://jsfiddle.net/eox0b8hq/ so the height won't be affected by the relative container.

Comment: @Pangloss thank you but fixed won't work cause body may be long.

Comment: Do you need the pink div to reach the viewport bottom or the page bottom when scrolls? If page bottom, your updated code won't work either - https://jsfiddle.net/n725s1nq/2/

Comment: @Pangloss Yes, and unfortunately I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: I guess it's hard to explain the purpose the the layout, I think you can probably achieve it with a different html structure.

Comment: @Pangloss For now I can only blame my English for inability to explain myself properly.. StackOverflow don't like when people publish ideas and ask ppl for code, so I tried to come up with the actual problem, but the solution is not solving it, unfortunately.

Comment: I made another example https://jsfiddle.net/dxtku36w/ I think that solves the height of the pink one, note I added another div inside second.

Comment: @Pangloss that's very impressive and very close to what I need, but since the first div height may vary, if you set it 50px instead of 100px for example, then the pink block won't hit bottom anymore.

Comment: For the first unknown height div, I don't know a solution yet, probably you need js, but as I mentioned if you can restructure the layout it might be doable, i guess you'll have figure that out on your own.

Comment: @Pangloss Thank you for your help. I appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on your update fiddle, since it's not that clear what you wish to achieve but you mentioned this example was close, I made your link to be above with `z-index` so it's clickable:

[Check external Fiddle, embedded seems to break bottom](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/n725s1nq/1/)

Comment: You can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/n725s1nq/1/ since the snippet messes up the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, will try to use this in my project. Yeah idea is that second div is a menu, and pink block is some sort of dropdown. And that dropdown need to hit bottom of the screen. But second block separated from top with an extra block. Seems like I will need to set position: relative to the whole page content. Since the second div is almost full screen overlay.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body > div { height: 100px; }

.first { background: lightblue; }

.second {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  top: 100px;
}

.second >div {
  background: pink;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="first">The height of the block may vary greately.</div>
<div class="second">
  <div>This DIV should take whole free space to the bottom of the screen.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would just avoid absolute as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, but I'm sorry, it's not what I need.